# The method 'after' does not work with elements not yet in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add two HTML elements to a Dom element one after another. But this call does not work with jQuery

```
$("<button>click me</button>").after("<span> or be happy </span>")
                              .appendTo("#someId");
```

The reason I cannot combine the two elements in one string is that I want to add a event handler to the first. So what I really want to do is:

```
$("<button>click me</button>").after("<span> or be happy </span>")
                              .on("click", function() {
                                  // do something
                              });
```

Right now, my workaround is to assign an id to the button and add the "span" in a separate jQuery call. Like so...

```
$('<button id="uid">click me</button>').on("click", function() {
                                            // do something
                                           });
$('#uid').after('<span> or be happy</span>');
```

It there a better way?

Comment: Saying something "does not work" is absolutely pointless, unless you go on to explain **what it does do** and **what it is you actually want to happen**.

Comment: Anthony, sorry. What I meant was that the second element (in this case "<span>...</span>") does not appear in the DOM. Only the button (along with the listener) is created and shows up appended to '#someId'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing it something like this then:

```
var _button = $('<button>')
                  .text('click me')
                  .on('click', function () { }),
    _span = $('<span>').text(' or be happy');

// not sure about the order, so just switch these two if ever
$('#foo').after(_button).after(_span);
```

#### EDIT

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/after/#disconnected-dom-nodes), you can actually insert DOM nodes (and manipulate) even if the nodes are not yet disconnected. This assumes jQuery 1.4+ though.

So if you fit that bill, you should be able to do all that in one statement:

```
$('<button>').text('click me')
             .on('click', function () {
                 // ...
             })
             .after('<span>')
                 .text(' or be happy')
                 .appendTo('#uid')
                 ;
```

Comment: Yup, that works. This is better than what I have. But it would have been great if the 'after' call could be made directly on the newly created element.

Comment: That's entirely possible, though it requires jQuery 1.4+ (which I'd argue you should be using jQuery 1.7+ anyway). Check out my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the `.after()` after the `.append()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kr9m4/

```
$("<button>click me</button>").on("click", function() {
    // do something
})
    .appendTo("#someId")
    .after("<span> or be happy </span>");
```

or like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kr9m4/1/

```
$("<button>", { text:"click me",
               click: function() {
                  // do something
               }})
    .appendTo("#someId")
    .after("<span> or be happy </span>");
```

Comment: This is good, but my app constraints prevent me from using the 'appendTo' call until after I have built the elements.